# Ajax request error 422 "Unprocessable Entity"

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get this json data from the twitch API: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/brunofin but I get an error 422 and the program stops. I know that the channel is unavailable but I need to display the message.

I'm using JQuery, here is my code:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/brunofin", function(data){
  console.log(data.message);
});
```

Is it possible to skip the error? What would be the best solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want to display? the json returned by the api is: {"error":"Unprocessable Entity","message":"Channel 'brunofin' is unavailable","status":422} do you want to display any of this or anything else?

Comment: I want to display the data.message. This is the error GET https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/brunofin 422 (status code 422). @superuseroi

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to do. you say you want to display data.message but that is already what you code is doing. Please be more specific

Comment: This helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458068/jquery-getjson-not-working-for-deleted-twitch-channel