# Api call using Ajax in javascript giving error

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i am getting error on calling ajax request with a code 422(unprocessible entity) , i dont understand what is wrong with my code can someone help me to figure out the error

```
         $.ajax({
            url: "/api/v3/email_exists",
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
              email: email_entered
            },
            success: function (response, status) {
                if (response.sent) {
                    showFlashMessage('Email Sent');
                    alert(response);
                }
                else {
                    showFlashMessage('An error occured, please try again latervrfg.', 'error');
                }
            },
            error: function (response, status) {
                showFlashMessage('An error occured, please try again later.', 'error');
            }
        });
```

url is returning either true or false in case of false it is giving status 422

Comment: what is the value of email_entered?

Comment: @ZaidYasyaf in case of success ada+1@ex.com and in case of failed testing+1@ex.com

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34458134/3673225

Answer (score 0):

Try with a full URL e,g https://Path_to _the controller_method